# flask app error: failed to load external entity. cannot input xml file for parsing

Tags: python, xml, flask

A python script which parses xml file runs independently fine but when it is called via views.py in flask it throws error. Even trying to parse xml file from views.py itself it throws error. Following are a couple of lines of code which throws error:

```
 from lxml import etree
 doc1=etree.parse('file.xml')
```

Error:

```
IOError: Error reading file 'file.xml': failed to load external entity "file.xml"
```

Comment: Does file.xml exist in the CWD of the python process? Does it work if you give it an absolute path? If not, could you share the contents of the xml file?

Comment: absolute path worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

where is your "file.xml" file ?, Put that file where view.py is

Or use absolute path

```
import os
from lxml import etree

ROOT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
file_path = ROOT_PATH + "/" + "file.xml"
doc1 = etree.parse(file_path)
```